How to save and use cookies for logging in to a website in python?
I want to login once and store my cookies so I don't have to login again, and each time I launch my code to be already logged in.
I've tried saving the cookies and inserting them back, but each time I launch the code I'm still not logged in.
I have tried using playwright and selenium.
Here the browser opens and I try to login manually and save the cookies to a file.
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver
import time
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website")

cookies = pickle.dump(cookies, open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))


Here after the file is created I try to add them back to the program, and start it again. It doesn't want to log in, though.
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver
import time
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website")

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
time.sleep(12)

Can anyone help?

Thanks for the code, but without whatever URL "website" actually is, the issue isn't reproducible.

You are adding cookies after making the web requests. You should be adding the cookies before making the web request.

It is also a bug to call driver.delete_all_cookies() within a for loop that adds cookies. You are literally deleting the cookies that you just added.

There are multiple issues with your code.

You are deleting all cookies within a for loop that adds the cookies
You never refresh the page after cookies are loaded

Ideally, you could add the cookies before making the initial web request, but Selenium appears to have a limitation that prevents this behavior because it won't allow for adding cookies until it knows the domain being accessed. If anyone knows a way around this, please inform.
A simple workaround is to just make the initial web request, add the cookies for that domain, then refresh the page with your set cookies.
Here is a solution that uses setcookie.net for testing. When you first run the script, set a cookie through the web interface. Press ENTER when done to save the cookies and end the script. Then, re-run the script and you'll see that cookies have been set.
import pickle
import os
import selenium.webdriver

# Create a fresh webdriver instance
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()


# Navigate to website
driver.get("https://setcookie.net/")

# Load cookies
if os.path.exists("cookies.pkl"):
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

    # Refresh the page with cookies (if set)
    driver.refresh()


# Hang to keep the browser open
input("Press Enter to close the browser...")

# Save cookies
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))


omg, thankyou for driver.delete_all_cookies() for lack of which my cookies were not getting processed correctly.

@Orwellophile you are welcome. Please considering marking this answer as the solution if it helped resolve your issue.
